# Не работают уведомления android

Tags: android, уведомления, android-notification

Написал стандартный код отображения уведомлений в MainActivity, но оно не отображается и не выдает ошибку.
Код в OnCreate:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Resources res = this.getResources();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.walk)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.route_notif_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.route_notif_text))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(112, notification);
```

Comment: Версия андроида какая?

Comment: @katso устройство Android 8.1 sdk 27, minSdkVersion 23 compileSdk 26

Comment: Вы не создали канал уведомлений, ваше уведомление ушло в dev/null. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо, все заработало